# Http Request using C# in Unity producing unexpecting results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I use the following code to run an http request I get some unexpected results from the `Debug.Log` statements:

```
StartCoroutine(UpdateUsersHttp(playerID,position,gameDataJson));
```

```
public IEnumerator UpdateUsersHttp(string playerID, Vector3 position,string gameDataJson) {
    Debug.Log("Update Users Http Called");
    string url =("http://url/UpdateUsers?playerID="+playerID);
    url =(url+"&updateJson="+gameDataJson);

    WWW www = new WWW (url);
    yield return www;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Error with url:{0}",url) + www.error);
        yield return www.error;
    }
    else {
        if (www.isDone) {
            Debug.Log(Time.time+" Updated Terrain Position "+www.text);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the `Debug.Log` after isDone to print:

```
12.33529 Updated Terrain Position (1.0, 0.0, -8.0)
```

But instead it prints 2 strings to the console and at different times:

```
12.38365 Updated Terrain Position (1.0, 0.0, -8.0)
12.42365 Updated Terrain Position (1.0, 0.0, -8.0)`
```

I'm not an expert on how Coroutines are implemented but could this mean I am running the http request twice? UnityWebRequest produced the same results. Is it possible the web server is somehow returning twice from the same http request ( I would think no).

Comment: What triggers your coroutine start?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]. It is way more likely that you just call `UpdateUsersHttp` twice than anything you've theorized in the post.

Comment: thank you, I'll try and see if I can repoduce it in a simplified example and post it. Apologies for not providing one.

Comment: If I was calling it twice I believe it would be printing 2 strings for ("Update Users Http Called"), which it is not.

Comment: There were two calls to two seperate StartCoroutines, one sends Debug.Log on completion, one sends a Debug.Log on start and completion (as above). Thanks for helping me narrow it down.